# How come the numerical integration is not $0$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am looking through some questions and answers from earlier exams, and the following problem has the solution (a) and (e). The thing that bothers me is that the integration goes from $-1$ to $1$, thus from calculus is going to be $0$?

**Problem:**
Let $p(x)$ be the interpolation polynomial to $f(x)=x^3$ on the nodes $x_0=-1, x_1=0, x_2=1$. Which statement is wrong?

*Answers:*

$\begin{align}
&(a) \int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1p(x)dx \\
&(b) \int_0^1p(x)dx=p(1/2) \\
&(c) \int_0^1p(x)dx=1/2(p(0)+p(1)) \\
&(d) \int_0^1p(x)dx=1/6(p(0+4p(1/2)+p(1))
\end{align}$

I know that (b) is a Midpoint rule, (c) is a Trapozoid and (d) is the Simpsons rule. My question is why does the intervals not go from $[-1,1]$? but from $[0,1]$? And therefore not the integration is not $0$?

Comment: I think the goal of the problem is to illustrate what happens when trying to apply the interpolation to a wrong interval. This should clear your question. As for the problem itself, just compute your $p(x)$ explicitly; the answer is then immediate.

Comment: I do not understand : $0$ is the correct result for the interval $[-1,1]$ and $x^3$, which we get with the simpson-rule which is exact upto degree $3$. The mid-point rule and the trapezoid-rule are only exact in general upto degree $1$. So what exactly bothers you ?